# Как распарсить строку в лямбду в Silverlight?

Tags: c#, парсер, silverlight

Кто-нибудь знает, можно ли в Silverlight распарсить строку в лямбду? Если да, то как?

Answer (score 2):

[Вот что нашлось на СodePlex](http://simproexpr.codeplex.com/)

PS: В крайнем случае, можно и свой велосипед написать

Answer (score 0):

Возможно [это](http://jplabs.bochi.it/2008/11/dynamic-lambda-expressions-using.html) поможет.